# Is there a way to use variable names to generate code in Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift, macros, c-preprocessor

In the past, using objective-c, my localization class has used a macro to generate a key from a variable name. The purpose was to allow for **auto-completion**, **remove the need to add a comment**, provide a simple way to add a **base language** in code, and keep the key-value pairs **in one place**. It resembled something like the following:

```
Localize(_theKey, "The default string")
```

Where `Localize` was a preprocessor macro:

```
#define GenerateKey(key) [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", CapitalizedClassName, [(@"" #key) substringFromIndex:1]]

#define Localize(key, defaultValue) key = NSLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue(GenerateKey(key), DefaultTable, DefaultBundle, defaultValue, DefaultComment)
```

Ultimately, this would generate a property initialised like this:

```
_theKey = NSLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue("Localization.Generic.theKey", DefaultTable, DefaultBundle, "The default string", "")
```

and I could access the localized string throughout my code with

```
[Localization Generic].theKey
```

---

I know that the preprocessor isn't available in Swift, however, is there a way to achieve the same thing?

**TL;DR; Is there any way I can use a macro<sup>1</sup> to use a variable name to generate code in Swift?**

I expect the answer to be "No". But I'll be pleasantly surprised if I'm wrong!

<sup>1. For lack of a better term, any solution is good!</sup>

Comment: Already uprooted, but here's a link: [link]https://swifting.io/blog/2016/11/20/27-localize-your-strings-swiftly/?utm_campaign=This%2BWeek%2Bin%2BSwift&utm_medium=email&utm_source=This_Week_in_Swift_111. My app currently isn't localized (I know, I know, I plan to get to this over the upcoming holidays) but if this helps, **please** post an answer.